# For Loop Inside BackgroundWorker.DoWork

Tags: vb.net, listview, backgroundworker

Basically, What I have is One background worker. A button gets clicked and that button has BackgroundWorker.DoWork The DoWork fucntion has this code:

```
For Each item In lst_Folders.CheckedItems
        Dim path As String = My.Settings.stng_sourceDirectory + "\" + item.Text
        For Each dirPath As String In Directory.GetDirectories(path, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
            Directory.CreateDirectory(dirPath.Replace(path, My.Settings.stng_saveDirectory + "\" + item.Text))
        Next

        'Copy all the files & Replaces any files with the same name
        For Each newPath As String In Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
            File.Copy(newPath, newPath.Replace(path, My.Settings.stng_saveDirectory + "\" + item.Text), True)
        Next
 Next
```

It's basically copying and pasting directories depending on which ListViewItem is checked. The problem is that Once I click on the button, the Background does work but immediately I get an error saying

`Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'lst_Folders' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.`

Can someone please assist me with this problem. I'm just not sure why it wont work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should only access UI control properties on the UI thread. When you run the background worker you can pass an argument to it. I'd recommend that you copy the values you need from the UI and pass them to the background worker as an argument, rather than letting the background worker read the UI directly.

For example inside your event handler do something like:

```
Private Sub startAsyncButton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles startAsyncButton.Click

    Dim folderNames As New List(Of String)
    For Each item In lst_Folders.CheckedItems
        folderNames.Add(item.Text)
    Next
    backgroundWork.RunWorkerAsync(folderNames)
```

And in you work method:

```
' This event handler is where the time-consuming work is done. 
Private Sub backgroundWorker1_DoWork(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
ByVal e As DoWorkEventArgs) Handles backgroundWorker1.DoWork
    Dim worker As BackgroundWorker = CType(sender, BackgroundWorker)
    Dim folderNames As List(of String) = CType(e.Argument, List(Of String))

    For Each folderName In folderNames
        Dim path As String = My.Settings.stng_sourceDirectory + "\" + folderName
    ' ...
```

For more information see: [BackgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync Method (Object)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f00zz5b2(v=vs.110).aspx)